# Gradle does not pull latest version from artifact repo?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

```
$ ./gradlew -v
Gradle 3.4.1
```

Old Gradle version, I know, but that's a different post.

We have a dependency in our `build.gradle` file like this

```
dependencies {
  compile("com.company.myservice:myservice-client:10.+")
}
```

I'm noticing that sometimes, the latest version is NOT fetched from the repository (Nexus in our case). **In other words**, if we push `myservice-client-10.9.0.jar`  to our repo, and then we run a build that has the dependency above, we use and older version, e.g., `10.8.x` that is in cache. Why is this? I know I can use `--refresh-dependencies` but I should not have to correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "sometimes", that's probably within 24 hours of the last update check, as [by default, Gradle caches dynamic modules for 24 hours](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dynamic_versions.html#sec:controlling_dependency_caching_programmatically). If you want to enforce an update check before 24 hours have passed, you indeed need to use `--refresh-dependencies`.

Or you lower the time for how long resolved versions will be cached like this (in Kotlin DSL):

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheDynamicVersionsFor(10, "minutes")
}
```

Comment: not working in gradle 7.5