# Gradle not downloading latest artifact version, despite major version change?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I posted [Gradle does not pull latest version from artifact repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66894152/gradle-does-not-pull-latest-version-from-artifact-repo) a month ago, and its answer made sense, and I implemented it and it worked.

However, if I change the major version, I'd expect Gradle to download it?

```
$ ./gradlew -v
Gradle 3.4.1
```

I changed from

```
dependencies {
  compile("com.company.myservice:myservice-client:10.+")
}
```

...to...

```
dependencies {
  compile("com.company.myservice:myservice-client:11.+")
}
```

but Gradle still used the latest `10.x` version? Why? I did fix it by also running the `--refresh-dependencies` option, but I don't understand why I needed to in this case?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Gradle 6/7. Did you try with a newer version?

Comment: Thank you. Yeah we're stuck with the older versions of Gradle b/c some of our projects are not compatible with the newer version. Thanks.